# Add permission check before sending the request to the file server

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as my reverse proxy server to fetch image from the file server, which is also a web server.

It works well. but I want add permission check based on the url before send request to my file server.  If has permission, just forwarding to my file server, or else just return 404.

BTW, I can't add the check in my file server for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

The module "http_auth_request_module" is what I want. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-request/